# How to set a template field using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am using iTextSharp to populate the fields of a PDF that has been created and secured by a third party (and we have no way of making modifications to it).

I have pre-populated the form before reading it in to help track down the values I need to set. This has worked well for most of the fields.

I am not too familiar with the inner workings of a PDF but I have made progress in that I can set all the fields bar one. The field in question is the UK National Insurance Number ('NINO'). It is formed of two letters, then three number pairs and a final single letter. e.g. JS 11 11 11 X

The jsonised XML Xfa.DatasetsSom.Name2Node node for the field looks like this:

```
"Q18": {
            "CompositeQuestion": {
              "NINO": {
                "QuestionArea": {
                  "HelpButton": {
                    "@xfa:dataNode": "dataGroup"
                  }
                },
                "NINO": {
                  "@xfa:dataNode": "dataGroup"
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

Rather than having the actual value in the node it appears to be pointing to a 'dataNode' 'dataGroup'. Not sure what this is. After browsing the object graph a bit I came across the Xfa.TemplateSom.Name2Node that appears to describe this template. here is it describing the first two letters:

```
"form1[0].AuthorisedOfficial[0].AuthOfficial[0].PanelBody[0].Column2[0].Q18[0].CompositeQuestion[0].NINO[0].NINO[0].Letters[0]": {
"field": {
  "@name": "Letters",
  "@w": "10mm",
  "@h": "6mm",
  "@locale": "en_GB",
  "ui": {
    "textEdit": {
      "@hScrollPolicy": "off",
      "border": {
        "@hand": "right",
        "fill": null,
        "edge": {
          "color": {
            "@value": "128,195,184"
          }
        },
        "corner": {
          "@thickness": "0.176mm",
          "color": {
            "@value": "128,195,184"
          }
        }
      },
      "comb": {
        "@numberOfCells": "2"
      }
    }
  },
  "font": {
    "@typeface": "Arial"
  },
  "margin": {
    "@topInset": "0mm",
    "@bottomInset": "0mm",
    "@leftInset": "0mm",
    "@rightInset": "0mm"
  },
  "para": {
    "@vAlign": "middle",
    "@marginLeft": "0pt",
    "@marginRight": "0pt",
    "@spaceBelow": "0pt"
  },
  "assist": {
    "speak": "National Insurance number first two letters"
  },
  "border": {
    "edge": {
      "@thickness": "0.1764mm",
      "@presence": "hidden",
      "color": {
        "@value": "128,195,184"
      }
    },
    "corner": {
      "@thickness": "0.176mm",
      "@presence": "hidden",
      "color": {
        "@value": "128,195,184"
      }
    }
  },
  "traversal": {
    "traverse": {
      "@ref": "Numbers1[0]"
    }
  },
  "bind": {
    "@match": "none"
  },
  "validate": {
    "message": {
      "text": {
        "@name": "scriptTest"
      }
    }
  },
  "format": {
    "picture": "text{AA}"
  },
  "event": [
    {
      "@activity": "change",
      "@name": "event__change",
      "script": {
        "@contentType": "application/x-javascript",
        "#text": "\tif (xfa.event.newText.length==2)\n\t\txfa.host.setFocus(Numbers1.somExpression);\n"
      }
    },
    {
      "@activity": "exit",
      "@name": "event__exit",
      "script": {
        "@contentType": "application/x-javascript",
        "#text": "\tif (this.rawValue != undefined) this.rawValue = this.rawValue.toUpperCase();\t\n\n"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

},

But again, there is no field that contains the value or a obvious place to set the value. It also appears to be referring to another template called Numbers1[0].

Here I draw a blank. My Question is, if possible, has anyone come across something similar and how to go about setting the values in the template and where in the iTextSharp pdfStamper the actual values are kept.

Fingers cross, thanks.

Comment: I'm not really into XFA but I would assume that people who are could best help if you shared both the PDF in question and a code sample of how you set the value of the critical field.

Comment: @mkl Yeah, good idea. I'll see if I can get permission to post the pdf. Cheers.